# gerund or infinitive with the verb going

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

> 1. I went to watch my girl friend playing drums yesterday
> 2. I went  watching my girl friend playing drums yesterday

First , is the last sentence correct? What is the difference between ***go +  gerund*** and ***go + infinitive***?

Comment: I think you should add more details in addition to your own opinion. The only "go + gerund" that I have faced so far is the case when "go" describes a movement. e.g., "she stumbled and her books went flying." **However, I am not sure whether it's an adjective or gerund**. Maybe I should ask a question on this.

Comment: The first example is correct. The second is incorrect. Most English verbs take the infinitive, and _to go_ is one of them. The Penguin Handbook page on the subject is **[here.](http://wps.pearsoned.ca/ca_ab_faigley_penghdbk_1/64/16478/4218569.cw/index.html)** (there is an excellent answer at ELU **[here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/330/192771)**

Comment: @Cardinal I think you will benefit from learning about **[The "Very" Test](https://literalminded.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/adjective-participle-or-gerund/)**!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for the link, but does it also work for the predicative adjective? ( I don't know what to call that "verb+ing" after went). In other words that test seems to be designed for the attributive adjectives. by the way it's cool.

Comment: @Cardinal Read that post closely: words in the predicative position are exactly what The Very Test is designed to test! (Can we say _"she stumbled and her books went **very** flying."_?)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ok, I just checked the flow-chart and skimmed the rest. I will check that carefully.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see. I didn't mean that specific sentence when I asked that question. I couldn't agree more. That's great.

Comment: Dant Reinstate Monica, based on what do you consider 2 wrong? "I went looking for space to rent yesterday"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "go + gerund " is used for individual  recreational activities and sports adventure. This is why you can say "go boating, go sailing, go bowling, go scuba diving, go shopping, go camping."

On that explanation, I can say if  Watching her playing guitars  is a recreational activity for you, then it's correct to say the number two. If not, then it's incorrect.

Comment: I agree with this.  "I went watching my girl friend play drums yesterday" does make it sound like her playing drums is a spectator sport.

Comment: Really, I think you overgeneralized and left some rare but still valid usage out of your explanation. "I went looking for space to rent yesterday" is a perfectly idiomatic sentence and I don't see it as a recreational activity.